# If we return a variable from a template function and we don't know what will be its data type how to get this returned variable in main function

Tags: c++, function, templates

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
T func()
{
   T a;
   cout<<"Enter value of a : ";
   cin>>a;
   return a;
}

int main()
{
    void*ptr;
    ptr=&func<void>();
    // How to get returned value from template function as i don't know what
    // will its data type???
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will be void, as you pass in void as `T`. It won't compile though.

Comment: That's where `auto` comes handy: `auto value = func<T>();`. Note the type is still assigned at compile-time, you just don't have to type it again. Your code is wrong - taking an address of temporary variable will leave `ptr` unsuable.

Comment: How to resolve this problem i want to get unknown variable and i don't know what will its data type   whether it is int or string or float or char i don't know as function is template so how to get this value ?

Answer (score 2):

You do know what type the function template returns, because you specify the return type as a type argument. That said, you can use type deduction place holder `auto` to let the compiler deduce that type:

```
int main()
{
    auto value = func<int>();
    // same as:
    //int value = func<int>();
}
```

---

You cannot instantiate the template `func<void>` because the template creates a variable of type `T` and `void` variables cannot be created.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword 'auto' for example

```
#include <string>

template<typename F>
auto call(F f) 
{
    return f();
}

std::string Hello()
{
    return std::string("Hello");
}

int main()
{
   int value = call([](){ return 42; }); // or also use auto value =
   std::string hello = call(Hello);      // or also use auto hello = 
}
```